# SQL int overflow - insert with encryption

Tags: sql, insert

I'm working on implementing encryption in MS SQL 2008R2. Loading data from a CVS file, I have that data in a temp table, and I now want to move some of that data into a encrypted credit card table. However, I keep getting the following error. Code for insert follows, table defs below.

The client ID is below 10 - the number causing the overflow is the very first line of data, CC number.

Error:

> Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The conversion of the varchar value '5105105105105100' overflowed an int column.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Insert statement:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY CreditCardKey
        DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CreditCardCert;

    insert into CreditCard
    Select
        HASHBYTES('SHA1', t.CreditCard),
        EncryptByKey(key_guid('CreditCardKey'), t.CreditCard),
        '',
        RIGHT(4, t.CreditCard),
        '1',
        t.Expiration,
        convert(int, t.ClientID)
    From TempTbl t
```

**TempTbl:**

- `ClientID int`.
- `First`, `Last`, `CC`, `Expiration` -- all `varchar(50)`.

All data appears to have imported correctly.

**CreditCard:** (destination table)

```
Hash varbinary(200)
Encrypted varbinary(400)
plaintext char(16)
lastfour int
servicecode int
expirationdate Date
ClientID int
```

Comment: Something, somewhere, is trying to convert a CC number to an `int`. There's only one obvious `int` conversion in the code you've posted - which shouldn't even be necessary if the columns are the types you've indicated - is this your actual code, or might you have over-sanitized it before posting it here?

Comment: No, it's a direct copy of what I'm executing in my query window... I'm now just thinking as I explain, I imported my data originally from a CVS, got an error and moved it into a new temp table with better data types... I assumed that it was/would have to be converted to fit in this new table, not sure if that could be it? (the move was a simple insert into... select *).

Comment: And what is `ClientID` in this new table - is it *actually* an `int`?

Comment: yes, I also removed that column and tried executing with a static '1' and it displayed the same error.

Comment: Syntax! =( RIGHT(t.CreditCard, 4). Thanks for your attention. In all seriousness, the culture of SO... delete this post?

Comment: Don't delete. Post your resolution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax issue was causing the overflow:
My use of the [RIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) function reversed the character and int offset, overflowing the integer expression of the function.

Correct use:

```
RIGHT ( character_expression , integer_expression )
```